# How to filter by a file extension in a graphql query

Tags: git, github, graphql, gatsby

I would like to query the content of markdown files inside a docs folder in a repository. I am using [gatsby-source-graphql](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-source-graphql/) and [GitHub v4 API](https://developer.github.com/v4/).

Thus far I've managed to get file contents with this code:

```graphql
{
  github {
    search(first: 1, type: REPOSITORY, query: "repo:kalessil/phpinspectionsea") {
      edges {
        node {
          ... on GitHub_Repository {
            folder: object(expression: "master:docs/") {
              ... on GitHub_Tree {
                entries {
                  oid
                  object {
                    ... on GitHub_Blob {
                      text
                    }
                  }
                  name
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that any type of file might end up inside the directory, such as `txt` and will require additional work to filter out.

Is there a way to query files only with `md` extension inside the `docs/` directory?

**EDIT:**

It is possible to accomplish in three steps. First by querying all files, filtering and then querying individual files:

```graphql
{
  github {
    files: search(first: 1, type: REPOSITORY, query: "repo:kalessil/phpinspectionsea") {
      edges {
        node {
          ... on GitHub_Repository {
            object(expression: "master:docs/") {
              ... on GitHub_Tree {
                entries {
                  name
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    content: search(first: 1, type: REPOSITORY, query: "repo:kalessil/phpinspectionsea") {
      edges {
        node {
          ... on GitHub_Repository {
            object(expression: "master:docs/DEVELOPERS.md") {
              ... on GitHub_Blob {
                text
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Maybe there is a better way?

**EDIT2:**

I've refactored the code according to [@robinmentral](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55774007/how-to-filter-by-a-file-extension-in-a-graphql-query#comment98236326_55774007) *(thank you)*:

```graphql
{
  github {
    files: repository(owner: "kalessil", name: "phpinspectionsea") {
      ... on GitHub_Repository {
        object(expression: "master:docs/") {
          ... on GitHub_Tree {
            entries {
              name
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    content: repository(owner: "kalessil", name: "phpinspectionsea") {
      ... on GitHub_Repository {
        object(expression: "master:docs/DEVELOPERS.md") {
          ... on GitHub_Blob {
            text
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But it still requires filtering on JavaScript side. As I need to get all the names first, filter out by extension and query only those files directly.

This is actually the right way to do in [gatsby-source-graphql](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-source-graphql/); for anyone who encounters this in the future check out their example project.

Now I'm just curious if it's possible to combine all these operations in one.

Comment: Seems like you worked it out! You could improve your Repository query with `repository(owner: "kalessil", name: "phpinspectionsea") { ... on Repository { ... } }` instead of using `search`.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Actually, I still don't know how to do it. It still takes GraphQL > JS > GraphQL to get the results, which does accomplish the task. Now I'm just curious if it's possible.

Comment: Don't know if it's possible, I've ran into similar issues I couldn't solve with the GitHub GraphQL API. And there's little help to be gained from StackOverflow, too new. You could try asking on the [GitHub community forums](https://github.community/t5/GitHub-API-Development-and/bd-p/api) if there's no further help here. I'm interested to see what you come up with!

Comment: As a side note, it's possible to remove `... on GitHub_Repository {}` and use `object` straight after `repository` query.

Answer (score 1):

Following up on my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55774007/how-to-filter-by-a-file-extension-in-a-graphql-query#comment98236326_55774007): if you want to query the contents of a specific file (like in your example), you could use this cleaner query:

```
{
  repository(owner: "kalessil", name: "phpinspectionsea") {
    ... on Github_Repository {
      object(expression: "master:docs/DEVELOPERS.md") {
        ... on Github_Blob {
          text
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```